# Rewrite configuration from HTTP to HTTPS not working

Tags: c#, .net, url-rewriting

In my .Net MVC website, How to add a rewrite rule to redirect my website url from http to https for my website with url "http://www.myleague.com"

Also, my website has few other domain like "http://www.mjleague.com.au" and "http://footballleague.com". I want to add a redirect rule, so that only "http://www.myleague.com" url is redirected to "https://www.myleague.com"

I'm trying with the following rule in the web.Config file and it is not working,

```
<rule name="HTTPtoHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^www.myleague.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
    redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Please let me know what i'm missing here

Comment: `my website` can we assume it as *apache* , or *nginx* :)

Comment: It is a .Net MVC website

Comment: a self hosted program or hosted in IIS :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed with the following configuration. Thank you all for replying.

```
                <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.myleague.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```